# Mac software Coda and Espresso can't print

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, coda, bbedit

Hello I'm currently having problems trying to print from Coda and Espresso.
I'm running Snow Leopard on an iMac and MacBook Pro.

When I try to print I get this error message.

> This error will cause instability and it is recommended you quit and relaunch Coda.
>   (NSInvalidArgumentException) -[NSError _addExceptionHandlerStackTrace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance **0×14ff4a60**

The part in bold changes each time I hit continue/ignore.
Printing does work for other programs, right now I print my code with BBEdit.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

First, Make sure that you are running the latest version of Coda...
Second, Make sure you have the latest print driver for your printer....
Third, Can you print to PDF through the print dialog?

If you can print to PDF, then it's a print driver issue.  That could mean that Coda is sending bad data to the print driver, or that the print driver is dying on some specific information that Coda is sending it.  (In other words, bad driver, or program bug)

If you **can't** print to PDF, then write up a bug with Panic, and find out what they need to debug this issue...

Comment: you mean "if you __can't__ print to PDF", right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct....

Answer (score 0):

I have no troubles printing in either, and I'm on 10.6 as well.

I would try a fresh reboot, if that doesn't solve it then removing (app zapping) Coda and reinstalling it.

After that, I would contact Panic with this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing to PDF? This might be a workaround if they have problems accessing the printer.